# Are data types in php categorized into reference type and value type? Like C#

Tags: c#, php, value-type, reference-type

In c#,data type is divided into reference type and value type.

Then in php,data type is still divided as c#?

I find a interesting thing.

array is a reference type in most language.

for example, in c#:

```
    int[] a ={1,4,5};
    int[] b = a;
    a[1] = 10;
    print(a);
    print(b)
```

both a and b are [1,10,5]

but in php,suppose there is below code:

```
<?php
$a=array(1,4,5);
$b=$a;
$a[1]=10;
print_r($a);
print_r($b);
?>
```

in the end, the $a is (1,10,5) and the $b is (1,4,5). It seems the array in php is value type.

So who can answer my question:
Are data types in php categorized into reference type and value type?

Comment: if you did `$b =& $a;` instead (in PHP), you would be referencing $a with $b and it would behave like C# [check the manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)

Comment: Are data types in php categorized into reference type and value type

Comment: Object is reference type and other is value type

Answer (score 3):

Yes, essentialy objects are stated to be reference type while **everything else is value type**. However, the former is not completely true and might be better described as 'pointer type'.

To give an example:

```
$a = new stdClass(); # <-- Obj1
$a->foo = 'foo';
$b = $a;
$b->foo = 'bar';
echo $b->foo; # outputs 'bar'
echo $a->foo; # outputs 'bar'
```

As you can see, it would seem that $a is being passed by reference; it is, however, actually a copy of the *identifier* of that object that is being passed. As such, updating a *property* will affect the original, but updating the *value* of the variable will not. This contrast with a true PHP reference as follows:

```
$c =& $a;
$c = new stdClass(); # <-- Obj2
$c->foo = 'foo';
echo $b->foo; # outputs 'bar'
echo $a->foo; # outputs 'foo'
```

Here we create a "true reference" of $a as/in $c. This holds that any alteration to $a will result in $c being altered and vice versa. As such, when we update the *value* of $c, $a is also updated and points to **Obj2**; meanwhile $b is left unaffected by the value being altered and still points to **Obj1**.

Comment: So array type in php can be thought as value type??

Comment: Yes, both associative and non-associative ones.